# windows 7 displayed twice on boot up

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I recently successfully installed windows 7 on a second hard drive via a usb port on my computer. I no longer have it plugged into the usb port, however, when I boot up the computer, it shows windows 7 twice, and I have to arrow down to the second one, in order to boot the computer up.  How can I eliminate the unnecessary windows 7 that was related to the usb?

Comment: You should backup your entire HDD before you run any tool that modifies your boot entry information.  [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) makes that easy.

Comment: Open run and type msconfig then move to boot tab and delete the usb boot file.

Comment: @Ramhound I've always found EasyBCD to be counterintuitive, especially with its limited support for EFI. I've always found Visual BCD to be more straightforward, even if the interface isn't as pretty.

Comment: I fixed this problem thru msconfig. Thanks for all the great answers!